# Why is getElementsByTagName not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What exactly is wrong with this code?

```
<p id="demo">Hello World!</p> 

<script>
document.getElementsByTagName('P').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
</script>
```

The background color is not getting changed to yellow.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array, so you can't apply the style property. `document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]` will work

Comment: Oh yes, silly me... Write that as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I think there are zillions of duplicated posts exactly with this question. DON'T FEED. Vote to close.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I found the dupe you were talking about

Comment: Don't edit new questions into your original question. If you have other questions, ask a seperate question (unless they have been asked before)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of objects. You need to specify the index inorder to apply the style property.

Use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the browser console to diagnose these kind issues. Your code triggers:

> TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).style is undefined
>
> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName('P').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
> ```

That means that whatever comes right before `style` is either not an object or it's an object but doesn't have a `style` property. To see what it is:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('P'));
```

You'll see it's an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is what [documentation for getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) says it should be.

In short, you need to pick an element, for instance the first one:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('P')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Or, to make your code more robust:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('P');
if (paragraphs.length>0) {
    paragraphs[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

Comment: I like the 'robust' part. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an Object that is iterable as an Array, you can have more one paragraph in your page, so in the first position there will be the first `<p>` tag that Javascript meets.

So, what you want is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('P')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
```

Comment: Why make it simple, when you can complicate? :) I see no reason in putting this in for loop when it comes to my example.

Comment: @Marcos, no you are. I never said the code is not fine. I need to style one element, not all of them. Why? Just for a testing purpose.

Comment: Implementing style to all 'p' tag have use loop. I guess you want to stylish all p tag. @super11

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `document.getElementById('demo')` if you only have one element to manipulate. It won't return an array as ids are exclusive to a single element.

Comment: Is it faster when there are no arrays?

Comment: With that you only select the `#demo` element, since there are only one.

Comment: This totally misses the point

Comment: I'm not sure of the time difference... but I'd guess that searching for a single element would be faster than having to search the DOM for multiple elements.

Answer (score -3):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. Not just one element.
Since array has a length property, you can select  specific element like this,

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName;
    paragraph1 = paragraphs[0];
    paragraph1.style.cssProperty = 'css value';
```

to select all elements you loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
     paragraph[i].style.cssProperty = 'css value'
   }
```

Inspect these stuff in your web console like this, you can see all element
   `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName)`

Comment: 5 other people said the exact same thing 10 mins ago